# Salesforce Updating Checkbox value on change event

Tags: checkbox, onchange, visualforce, apex

Here hidden_field__c is a checkbox. 
When in the VFP if user changes the checkbox to true in the database it still shows as false and vice-versa 
Can someone please point out what's missing in my code.? 
This is my code.

**-----------controller --------------**

```
public class dataTableCon {

    List<Account> accounts;

    public List<Account> getAccounts() {

        if(accounts == null) accounts = [select name, owner.name,hidden_field__c from account limit 10];

        return accounts;

    }

}
```

**---------VFP-------------**

```
<apex:page controller="dataTableCon" id="page">

    <apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock id="theBlock">

    <apex:dataTable value="{!accounts}" var="account" id="theTable" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Private</apex:facet>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!account.hidden_field__c}" >
             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="theBlock"/>
           </apex:inputCheckbox>           
        </apex:column>


        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!account.name}"  >
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!account.owner.name}"  >
        </apex:column>

    </apex:dataTable> 

    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some mechanism that actually saves the changes. Try adding an [<apex:commandButton>](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm) inside your <apex:form>, and then have that button call an action that saves.

Apex:

```
public PageReference save()
{
  update accounts;
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
```